# Is it possible to power a 4K display at 60 Hz with a DisplayPort/HDMI adapter connected to a USB-C hub?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I have a LG display which supports 4K at 60 Hz. I wanted to buy an adapter for my Macbook Air(2018) to use it with my notebook. I am confused about one thing though. I have read that USB-C to USB-C hubs don't exist. So, am I limited to using the one free port left after using one for power to be either occupied by DisplayPort adapters or something else one at a time?

I have seen that Apple and some other manufacturers have a USB-C to multi AV adapter which has HDMI and USB-C both as output but can't find one for DisplayPort. Is this because of higher requirements of the DisplayPort 1.3+ standard which allows it to do 4K 60 Hz not leaving bandwidth for multiplexing the port?

Comment: Please edit your question, or add into a comment, the LD device model name # number. If your LG has a HDMI port, you can use [this Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b) to breakout into HDMI, USBC and USB3

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback. It has a Display Port and 2 HDMI ports. I think I already mentioned looking at the Apple adapter but that is HDMI, I wanted the same for DisplayPort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2018 MacBook Air actually has 2 Thunderbolt 3 ports. I.e. they not just USB-C ports.

This mean that you can definitely connect all sorts of multiport adapters, docks, etc. to enable you to charge the Mac while connected to a DisplayPort monitor - and then even more.

Just as an example you can use the OWC Thunderbolt 3 dock and connect that to one of the two Thunderbolt 3 ports on your MacBook Air. It comes with a power brick that will charge your MacBook Air through that single cable. In addition it has a 4k at 60Hz DisplayPort output (you'll need a mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable).

This leaves you with one of the two ports on your MacBook Air unused - as well as providing lots of extra ports on the dock itself (5 x USB 3, 1 x USB-C, 1 x daisy-chained Thunderbolt 3, ethernet, S/PDIF, audio-jack, SD-card and micro-SD).

In fact you could also use the daisy-chained Thunderbolt 3 port to hook up the monitor - then you would require a USB-C to DisplayPort cable instead.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was a Thunderbolt 3 port. I looked at the OWC adapter and seems something like that would do the job. Thanks